# Can't get html events in listbox to work

Tags: html, events, listbox

I'm just getting started in web programming and so I'm sure this is a very elementary error--but I can't get events to fire within an html listbox.  Here's my test.html in its entirety:

```
<html><body>

<select name="drop1" id="Select1" size="4" multiple="multiple" onchange="alert('Click');">

    <option value="1" onselect="alert('Click');">item 1</option>

    <option value="2">item 2</option>

    <option value="3">item 3</option>

    <option value="4">item 4</option>

    <option value="0">All</option>

</select>

</body></html>
```

I get the the same result--nothing happens when I click on any item in the list--when I put in the name of a php script instead of 'alert'.  What am I missing?  I have googled around a fair bit but haven't found anything.

EDIT: So it turns out this problem (specifically with 'alert') is browser-specific.  In Chrome, you need the javascript: prefix as pointed out by EmCo.  But in Firefox the above executes fine as is.

Comment: I think you nedd this: `onchange="javascript: alert('Click');"`

Comment: What do you mean: `when I put in the name of a php script` ?

Comment: I mean something like onchange="myfile.php"

Comment: @Matt: That's not how it works. What exactly do you want it to do when it changes?

Comment: @EmCo That was it, for this example!  What I'm ultimately after is having what the user clicks on get posted to a php file which then handles it, but fair's fair--'answer' with the above if you want the rep :)

Comment: @jnpcl I want behavior analogous to what happens when you use a php script to handle an html form with e.g. simple input text fields.  Examples this are everywhere, but I haven't found one for listboxes.  You click on "item 4" and 'item 4' is set as the value of some global which then gets POSTed.

Comment: @Matt: I think you may be trying to recreate functionality that already exists. When your form is submitted, all named elements will be sent to the form's `action` page via the form's `method` (`POST` or `GET`). You shouldn't need to manually "set as the value of some global which then gets POSTed"

Comment: @jnpcl How do you incorporate a listbox into a form? All the examples I could find with forms/php just used input text fields. When I simply enclose the listbox with form tags (as I would for a text field) nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted works for me, in that is shows the JavaScript `alert()` when the selection in the `select` changes.  However, I'm concerned about where you say this:

> when I put in the name of a **php script** instead of 'alert'

Two things:

1. Show us the actual code that's failing, please.
2. How are you trying to call a "PHP script" from HTML/JavaScript?  PHP is a server-side technology, HTML and JavaScript are client-side.  You say you're just getting started, so it sounds like you're running into the disconnect between the server and the client and aren't sure how to proceed.

PHP functions can't be called directly in the browser in the manner I suspect you're trying.  By the time the page is delivered to the browser, the entire PHP script has already run.  What you're left with is HTML and JavaScript on the client-side (in the browser).  There are a lot of more advanced things you can do with JavaScript, including even making AJAX calls back to server resources (which are written in PHP, but again will emit only client-side stuff) and respond to the output of those resources.

What, ultimately, are you trying to do when the selection of the `select` changes?

Comment: 1. I did, that was it in its entirety. 2. Within a <form> tag, you can have action="myscript.php" and the subsequent input widget will call myscript.php and POST a value.  (For e.g. a simple text field.)  I'm trying to do the same thing here, except with a listbox, where the selected value is what gets posted.

Comment: @Matt Phillips: Then where does PHP come in?  And how is the posted code not working?  I copied/pasted it into jsfiddle.net and it displayed the JavaScript `alert()` exactly as it was supposed to.

Comment: @David didn't realize re this comment you were the OP of this answer <blush>.  The error is browser-specific, you need javascript: as EmCo said, in Chrome but not Firefox.  I want the listbox selection to get 'handled' with a php script in the same manner that a standard html form with e.g. input text boxes would.

Comment: @Matt Phillips: Ah, I see.  Well, how you want it to be "handled" and what you want to accomplish will affect how to go about doing that.  Do you want it to do something in the background, such as with AJAX?  Or do you want it to actually post the form?  The former can get complex depending on what you need, but the latter should be easy enough.  Take a look here: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Comment: @Matt Phillips: Based on your comments above, it sounds like you actually want to post the form as normal, you're just not seeing the `select` value in the server-side code?  A number of things could be causing this.  How are you accessing the value in the server-side code?  In the code provided, the selected value should be in the form value `drop1` when posted to the server.  If you reduce the client-side code to only the `select` in the form, and the server-side code to only accessing that one value, where does it fail?

Comment: @David Thanks, that looks promising.  I'm wondering if Javascript is necessary for this (though I do plan to learn it in any case) and if the tutorial you referenced will explain simply how to treat a listbox as a form, I haven't been able to figure that out yet.

Comment: @David How do I get the listbox to be treated as a form, or otherwise post?  jnpcl has an answer that makes use of a submit button, but I want the action triggered directly by the listbox selection.

Comment: @Matt Phillips: The `select` element (what you're calling a listbox) is a form element like any other.  Note that in your sample code in the question, there is no actual `form` tag and therefore no form posting going on.  But if you include a named `select` element with other named form elements (`input`s of type text as you mentioned in a comment elsewhere, for example) then the value of its selected `option` element will be posted along with the text values of the other elements.  Do you have an example where this is not the case?

Comment: @David, if I simply enclose the <select> in <form action="testlist.php" method="POST"> ... </form> nothing is submitted, I presume because <input> elements are still needed.  But where do they go?  I tried to insert one (type="text") within the option tags, it just produced an input text field (which I do not want).

Comment: @Matt Plillips: When you say "nothing is submitted" do you mean that the form posts but there is no value for the `select` available to the server-side script, or that the form doesn't post?  For a traditional form you would at least need an `input` of type `submit` (a submit button) to post the form.  (Unless yo do it with JavaScript like in that link I posted.)  Then, on the server-side, how are you trying to access the posted value?

Comment: @David, I'm not sure whether the form posts or not.  I really don't want a separate button, but rather to do in-page updating when the user selects on a list item.  It seems pretty clear to me at this point that JavaScript is the answer.  (Takes me a little by surprise, I come from a C++/gui background where what I'm trying to do is trivial.)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Matt Phillips: I'd say the biggest thing to be careful of is the principle of least astonishment.  That is, if the website starts doing things users don't expect, you could run into issues.  For example, a post-back when a form element changes might be unintuitive, especially if there are also other input elements in the form.  (Maintaining the existing values in those elements through the post-back is another consideration, users hate filling in data just to lose it on an unexpected post-back.)  Definitely look into AJAX (easily done with jQuery) for behind-the-scenes client-server logic.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in a comment above, I think you're trying to recreate functionality that already exists.

When you `Submit` your `<form>`, all named elements and their values are sent to the page specified in the `action` attribute, via the `method` attribute in your `<form>` element.

**Example:**

---

**www.mysite.com/myform.html**

```
<form action="myscript.php" method="POST">
    <select name="drop1[]" size="4" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">item 1</option>
        <option value="2">item 2</option>
        <option value="3">item 3</option>
        <option value="4">item 4</option>
        <option value="0">All</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

**www.mysite.com/myscript.php**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        print_r($_POST);
    } else {
        echo 'No data!';
    }
?>
```

---

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [drop1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

    [submit] => Submit
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, but it's not quite doing what I want.  I basically want the functionality you've just described here but without a separate 'Submit' button.  I.e. the form is submitted/action is performed as soon as the user clicks on a list item.  (This is for what will be a frequently-used interface, where the extra click demanded by the 'Submit' button would get pretty annoying.)

Comment: @Matt: Then what you're looking for is AJAX, and I'm not certain how that would function in a multi-select listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run PHP script directly from client side events.

What you need is AJAX, on change of the drop down list trigger AJAX request to the server that will invoke the desired PHP script.

You can then read the response and act according to it.

Comment: Well, if a php script is given as a form action=, it will get called with POSTed variables.  That's essentially what I'm trying to do here, is there some way to incorporate a list box into an html form?

Comment: @Matt - You need the form to be submitted for this.. so just have this in the `<select>` to have it auto submit the form when changed: `onchange="this.form.submit();"` if this is indeed what you need let me know and I'll edit my answer.